# WebBrowsers don't obey ProxyFire rules

Tags: vpn, routing, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, google-chrome

I am using **ProxyFire** portable v.3.42 on **Windows** to route all my system network traffic over LocalHost.

In **MobaXTerm**(same as Putty) I have set a **SSH Tunnel by forwarding 127.0.0.1:4567 into my server**.

Through this configuration , I expect every application's network traffic on my Windows , rout through this SSH proxy , Including Chrome !

**But it seems Chrome doesn't obey Proxyfire rules**. It doesn't affect on Chrome or I did something wrong.(other Apps are OK).

I have tried different web browsers such as IE and Edge but it didn't work.

It has problem with web browsers.

Here are screenshots :

ProxyFire Proxy Server :

[image]

ProxyFire Rule :

[image]

Bellow you can see that it works great with Telegram but **there is no Chrome !** :

[image]

Here is my Internet Option Lan Setting by the way :

[image]

I want to know why these configurations don't affect on web browsers ?
And how can I fix that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using portable version of Proxifier you need to modify something in proxification engine section.
Go to **Profile** > **Advanced** > **Proxification Engine...** and there in both 32bit & 64 bit subsystem make sure `Intercept network calls at` is set to `WinSock Library (ws2_32.dll)` and `Hook type` is `Function Prologue Copy` then reboot your PC/Laptop and there you go! Also as a more easy & quick way just use the installable version instead of portable